# Reuse a complex non-deterministic expression in SELECT and WHERE clauses

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
-- This is inefficient, and may even be wrong if expression is nondeterministic
SELECT TOP 10 team_name,score_points=<big expression>
  FROM teams
 WHERE <big expression> >= 100
 ORDER BY 2 DESC

-- This gives error
SELECT TOP 10 team_name,score_points=<big expression>
  FROM teams
 WHERE score_points >= 100
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

What I want to do is clear: list the teams with the highest score_points. List all teams with at least 100 score_points, but no more than 10 teams.

If I repeat the expression, it will be very ugly and inefficient. Plus, it will give wrong results when my expression is not deterministic.
Using the name `score_points` in the `WHERE` clause gives an error.
Is there an efficient way to have the results of my expression both returned as a column in my query, and used as a filter?

Please don't tell me about computed columns, I know about them but I can't use them here.

Comment: It may be ugly but where did you get that it will be inefficient? Did you test?

Comment: unfortunately we're probably going to need to see this non-deterministic expression

Answer (score 6):

This can't help with the determinism issue, but `CROSS APPLY` is a good tool for big expressions that need to be reused:

```
SELECT TOP 10 team_name, CxA.Score_Points
FROM teams t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Score_Points = <big Expression, refer to t>) CxA
 WHERE CxA.Score_Points >= 100
 ORDER BY CxA.Score_Points DESC
```

`CROSS APPLY` expressions get calculated for every row and can be referred to in any part of the query.

Comment: On second thought this may take care of determinism too, since the calculation is only run once per row.

Comment: This is *quite likely* to work, but it is not guaranteed. SQL Server does not guarantee the timing or number of evaluations of expressions. Even where it seems 'obvious' from the query text that evaluation only occurs once, the optimizer may produce a plan with different runtime characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the determinism issue using a CTE or a derived table, as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 10 team_name, score_points
 FROM 
    (SELECT team_name, score_points=<big expression>
     FROM teams) T
 WHERE score_points >= 100
 ORDER BY score_points DESC
```

Should you still encounter performance problems, probably there could be something to revise in your  calculation